# The array in my singleton isn't keeping information after leaving a function and then it crashes when it tries to access the information again

Tags: c++

I have an array called `int **grid` that is set up in `Amazon::initGrid()` and is made to be a `[16][16]` grid with `new`.  I set every array value to 0 and then set `[2][2]` to 32.  Now when I leave `initGrid()` and come back in `getGrid()` it has lost its value and is now 0x0000.

I don't know what to try, the solution seems to be really simple, but I'm just not getting it.  Somehow the data isn't being kept in `g_amazon` but I could post the code.

```
// Returns a pointer to grid
int** Amazon::getGridVal()
{
    char buf[100];
    sprintf_s(buf, "Hello %d\n", grid[2][2]);
    return grid;
}

int Amazon::initGrid()
{
    int** grid = 0;
    grid = new int* [16];
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        grid[i] = new int[16];

        for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
        {
            grid[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }


    grid[2][2] = 32;

    return 0;
}

int **grid;
g_amazon = Amazon::getInstance();
g_amazon->initGrid();
grid = g_amazon->getGridVal();

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
    {
        int index;
        index = (width * 4 * i) + (4 * j);
        int gridval;
        gridval = grid[i][j];
        lpBits[index] = gridval;
        lpBits[index + 1] = gridval;
        lpBits[index + 2] = gridval;
    }
}
```

It crashes when I run it at the line where `sprintf_s` prints out `[2][2]` and it also crashes when I get to `gridval = grid[i][j]` because it's at memory location 0x000000.

Comment: You have a couple of ***different*** variables named `grid`. Perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: `initGrid()` has its own local `grid` variable, which leaks memory when `initGrid()` exits. The `grid` variable returned by `getGridVal()` is not initialized (where is that variable coming from?).  In general, this is not good C++ code. Consider using `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` or `std::array<std::array<int,16>, 16>` instead. There is no good reason to use `new[]` manually in this situation.

Comment: I have grid as an int** grid; in  class Amazon {}; so shouldn't it stay in memory or do I need a static var.

Answer (score 1):

The variable

> int** grid

in the initGrid() function is a local variable. Edit** When the function returns the variable is popped off the stack. However, since it was declared with the new operator the memory still exists on the heap; it is simply just not pointed to by your global grid variable.

Answer (score 0):

@Dean said in comment:

> I have grid as an int** grid; in class Amazon {}; so shouldn't it stay in memory or do I need a static var.

That is the problem:

local `int **grid;` on `Amazon::initGrid::`

is masking

member `int **grid;` on `Amazon::`

as the first **context** has higher priority in **name lookup**.

So `initGrid()` allocates memory referenced only by a local pointer. That pointer no longer exists when you return from this function, `Amazon::grid` was never touched on initialization and you're also left with some **bad memory issues**.

So, as commented by @Remy-Lebeau, I also suggest

> Consider using std::vector> or std::array, 16> instead. There is no good reason to use new[] manually in this situation.

Comment: I was able to get the int **grid to work eventually, but I was left wondering about GDI+ when I wanted to put the grid on the screen.  Is GDI+ maintained currently any more or do most people use DirectX or what?  I just ask because that CreateCompatibleDC and stuff just to put rectangles on the screen seems distracting.

Comment: @Dean this is an entirely different question (and you'll need to provide more information). About this question, I hope now you understand what was wrong.